# Android Custom XML Objects

Tags: android, xml, list, resources

Once in a while I want to populate a list with items that are static, what/where is the best way to store those static items?

I normally use an xml resource with something like this:

```
<string-array name="category_ids">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>

<array name="category_titles">
    <item>@string/category_all</item>
    <item>@string/category_new</item>
    <item>@string/category_hot</item>
</array>

<array name="category_icon_ids">
    <item>@null</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_category_star</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_category_thumb</item>
</array>
```

I access these arrays and populate an adapter with custom objects. But it annoys me every time I use it. When I change the order in the list for example, I have to change every array in the xml.

Is there a better solution? Are custom XML objects supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when working with Custom Objects that can vary, accessing and populating these items with an adapter can be very stressful.

Instead, you can use `json` to handle more complex objects than with simple arrays.

Here's an example of a json implementation:

In the `/res/raw` folder:

```
{ "countries" : [
    {"country" : "Albania", "countryCode" : "al" },
    {"country" : "Algeria", "countryCode" : "dz"},
    {"country" : "American Samoa", "countryCode" : "as"},
    {"country" : "India", "countryCode" : "in"},
    {"country" : "South Africa", "countryCode" : "sa"}
]}
```

Loading data in your class:

```
InputStream jsonStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.countries);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Strings.convertStreamToString(jsonStream));
JSONArray jsonContries = jsonObject.getJSONArray("countries");
List<CountryVO> countries = new ArrayList<CountryVO>();
for (int i = 0, m = countries.length(); i < m; i++) {
    JSONObject jsonCountry = countries.getJSONObject(i);
    CountryVO country = new CountryVO();
    country.setCountryName(jsonCountry.getString("country"));
    String co = jsonCountry.getString("countryCode");
    country.setCountryCode(co);
    try {
        Class<?> drawableClass = com.example.R.drawable.class; // replace package
        Field drawableField = drawableClass.getField(co);
        int drawableId = (Integer)drawableField.get(null);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
        country.setCountryFlag(drawable);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // report exception
     }
     countries.add(country);
}
```

If you don't want to do the parsing manually you can use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to pass the objects and load the drawables.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9809772/1549700

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can have your custom `xml`, stored under `res/xml/`, but in this case accessing the content is not exactly free. You can use  `getResources().getXml(R.xml.name_of_file)`, to retrieve an instance of  [XmlResourceParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html), which you have to use to parse the xml