# How can I insert List of object on resource file?

Tags: android

I want to populate a `Spinner` element with a List of element. I don't want to store this information on database, but I want to insert this option in one resource file.

So I have insert this code on String.xml file:

```
   <string-array name="sports_array">
        <item>Shuttle Badminton</item>
        <item>Tennis</item>
        <item>FootBall</item>
        <item>Basket Ball</item>
        <item>Table Tennis</item>
        <item>Chess</item>
        <item>Hockey</item>
    </string-array>
```

Now this is not good because I should to have other information like this:

> Code:1
>   Name: Tennis
>   CodeSystem: 1000.150
>   Version: 1

At the end, I want to have also other information than at the Name.

It is possible?

Comment: You can keep local json copy in assets . Read from assets in model and perform operation

Comment: If you have a list of static objects you can create a class with all your data inside.

Comment: why you don't create an item like this <item>Code:1 Name: Tennis CodeSystem: 1000.150 Version: 1
</item>

Comment: I can't use that code, because, I must use the information and I wan't do a slip operation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeArray in Android - How to store custom objects in xml and retrieve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774579/typearray-in-android-how-to-store-custom-objects-in-xml-and-retrieve-them)