# ClassCastException inside MainActivityBinding

Tags: android, classcastexception, android-databinding

When trying to add data binding to my app, I see a crash after a `ClassCastException` *inside* `MainActivityBinding`. Here is the stack trace:

```
com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.myapp, PID: 15524
                                                                  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
                                                                      at com.mayapp.databinding.MainActivityBinding.executeBindings(MainActivityBinding.java:553)
                                                                      at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:379)
                                                                      at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:351)
                                                                      at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$6.run(ViewDataBinding.java:178)
                                                                      at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$5.onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewDataBinding.java:146)
                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:17392)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3319)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1658)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Inside `main_activity.xml` I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="tiles"
            type="com.myapp.Tile[]" />
    </data>
    ...
```

`Tile[]` is underlined giving me the "Cannot resolve symbol ..." error which I chose to ignore since the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) say:

> Note: Arrays and a generic type, such as the Observable class, might display errors when there are no errors.

The gradle build is successful, however, when I run the app on an emulator or on a physical device I get the above error.

When I follow the link from the stack trace I can actually enter `MainActivityBinding`. Among a lot of code I find the following method marked by the compiler:

```
public boolean setVariable(int variableId, Object variable) {
    switch(variableId) {
        case BR.tiles :
            setTiles((com.myapp.Tile[]) variable);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`BR.tiles` is underlined and the compiler tells me: "Constant expression required".

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The `BR.tiles` part most likely is unavoidable; use `if` instead of `switch`. With regards to the crash, you have a binding expression that is evaluating to an `int` or `Integer` on some attribute that needs a `CharSequence`.

Comment: The error is inside the auto-generated `MainActivityBinding`. I can't change the code there, right?

Comment: Also, I checked: `BR.tiles` is `public static final int`. So why does the compiler complain anyway?

Comment: @CommonsWare The other part of your comment led me on the right track. I had the following expression inside my XML: `android:text='@{tiles[0].getValue == 0 ? "" : tiles[0].getValue}'` in order to print nothing if value == 0 else print value. Yet the "false side" of the ternary evaluates to an int. I put String.valueOf(tiles[0].getValue) and it works. Care for some more rep? Probably not, but if so, write an answer, I will check and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When trying to add data binding to my app, I see a crash after a `ClassCastException` inside `MainActivityBinding`.

Based on the error, you have a binding expression that evaluates to an `int` or `Integer`, but the attribute is expecting a `CharSequence`.

> I had the following expression inside my XML: `android:text='@{tiles[0].getValue == 0 ? "" : tiles[0].getValue}'` in order to print nothing if value == 0 else print value. Yet the "false side" of the ternary evaluates to an int. I put `String.valueOf(tiles[0].getValue)` and it works.

Usually, if you pass an `int` to `android:text` via a binding expression, it compiles fine, but then if the `int` is not a string resource ID, you crash on that (`ResourceNotFoundException`). My guess is that the data binding framework is assuming that you want `setText(CharSequence)` due to the `""` and is explicitly casting the ternary result to `CharSequence`, which then crashes when an `Integer` cannot be cast that way.

Personally, I am moving away from using this sort of binding expression, instead populating some sort of true "view model" where this logic is in Java (easier to debug, easier to test) and binding against it, so the binding expressions are simpler.

> I checked: BR.tiles is public static final int. So why does the compiler complain anyway?

That's a good question. I had assumed that it was declared in such a way that `switch` did not like.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable of type integer like,

```
<data>
<integer
        name="tiles">integer
</integer>
</data>
```

as you are assigning integer value to XML variable.

Comment: Compiler: "Element integer not allowed here" (even without the "free" integer inside the element). My variables are not integers anyway. It is an array of my custom-made `Tile`.

Comment: Please refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774579/typearray-in-android-how-to-store-custom-objects-in-xml-and-retrieve-them  Let me is it helpful or not.

Comment: The link is not helpful. The question there is about how to make a array from resources. My question is about data binding. There is no direct relationship.